# How to get the correct measure result in different context filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have imported two tables into Power BI and created a 1:M relationship between Project and Project Status.

[image]

[image]

I created two measures containing the expression `COUNT([ProjectId])` under the **Project** and **ProjectStatus** queries called 'Project Count From Project' and 'Project Count From Project Status' respectively.

However the result 'Project Count From Project' shows all the rows. In my scenario how can I create one measure which will give me the correct result whether I'm counting number of projects by status or number of projects a project member participates in.

[image]

I'm very keen to understand why the **'Project Count From Project'** measure doesn't work. It would be nice to create just one measure that can be used for the same purpose, ie, to count the number of projects according to the context filter.
For example, let's suppose I create a table called Project Members. I shouldn't have to create another measure in ProjectMembers query to show how many projects each member belongs to.

Comment: Your required output is not clear. You wants to show both value in single visual? That case single measure will not work. If you wants to show them in separate table visual, please show your expected output separately and based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the relationship you need to set the cross filter direction to both, because you have it only one direction it means that the filter on Status is not being applied to the projects table.

[image]

If you have it set with both, then you only need 1 measure and it doesn't really matter where you create it, although I would do it on the table where you have the list of Projects.

Comment: Obrigado, Joao. Resposta correta. Thanks, Joao, you're right.